# Getting a Filter to handle a Promised Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have already started to rework this code to operate synchronously, but out of curiosity and a desire to support both means, I need some help understanding how to get a filter to jive with a promise. As some other posts mention a filter seems to just resolve to {} from a promise.

### Basic Pattern

Here's a breakdown:

1. Define a service in the module that returns a promise instead of an object

   ```
   module.factory('promisedSvc', ['$http', function($http) {

     var httpPromise = null,
       servicePromise = null,
       service = {},
       dataSet = {};

     var httpPromise = $http.get('somedata.json').success(function(data) {
       dataSet = data;
     });

     servicePromise = httpPromise.then(function(){
       service.getData = function(key) {
         return dataSet[key];
       };

       service.addData = function(key, value) {
         dataSet[key] = value;
       };

       return service;
     });

     /*
       In actuality I proxied the service methods onto the promise because
       I didn't want consumers of the service to have to deal with it being
       a promise. There is the caveat of setting properties on a class I 
       don't own (property collisions), a risk I'm okay taking, but YMMV

       Commented out proxies
       servicePromise.getData = function(key) {
         return this.then(function(svc){
           return svc.getData(key);
         });
       };

       servicePromise.addData = function(key, value) {
         this.then(function(svc){
           svc.addData(key, value);
         });
       };
     */

     return servicePromise;
   }]);
   ```
2. Controllers can handle this `promisedSvc` fine, you just get the promise injected into the controller and then use the `then` function on the promise  to wrap the setting of a `$scope` property to the function call on the eventual service object: `getData(key)` or `setData(key, value)`. Alternately you can just treat it as normal if you proxied the functions onto the promise like in the commented out block.
3. Filters do not seem to inherently handle promises like `$scope` does. I am looking for a way to get the filter to inject the `promisedSvc` and be able to call `getData(key)` without it resolving to `{}` because the promise has not resolved yet. Below is an example of what does not work:

   ```
   module.filter('svcData', ['promisedSvc', function(promisedSvc) {
     return function(input) {

       return promisedSvc.then(function(svc) {
         var value = svc.getData(input);
         return value;
       });
     };
   }]);
   ```

So is there a way to write the filter to be able to resolve the value?

### Use Case

That is the simplified pattern of what I am trying to achieve. For those curious, my actual use case is to pre-fetch i18n/l10n resource bundle information so I can localize all the text in my application. The pre-fetch could all be in the Javascript environment (attached to some already loaded global or in a provider), but we also have scenarios with database-stored Resource Bundles so I needed a version of code that can pre-fetch all the information from the server via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but at least to document a workaround:

It's possible to use a function on the $scope instead of a filter.

```
module.factory('promisedSvc', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {

  var httpPromise = null,
    servicePromise = null,
    service = {},
    dataSet = {};

  var httpPromise = $http.get('somedata.json').success(function(data) {
    dataSet = data;
  });

  servicePromise = httpPromise.then(function(){
    service.getData = function(key) {
      return dataSet[key];
    };

    service.addData = function(key, value) {
      dataSet[key] = value;
    };

    //Here is the addition to setup the function on the rootScope
    $rootScope.svcData = function(key) {
      return service.getData(key);
    };

    return service;
  });

  return servicePromise;
}]);
```

And then in a template instead of `{{ 'key1' | svcData }}` you would use `{{ svcData('key1') }}`

I tested that if you delay the promises resolution (for example setup a wait in the `$http.success`) that the impact is the page loads, but the values from the svcData function will only populate into the template once the promises resolve.

Still would be nice to accomplish the same with a filter if possible.